# Redirecting non-www and www (http) to https

Tags: redirect, apache2, debian

My goal is to redirect any non-www and www from a http connection to a https connection while keeping the full path.

For example:

```
http://example.com/something/
http://www.example.com/something/
```

should redirect to:

```
https://example.com/something/
```

I have included this in the sites-available/default.conf

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it doesn't work. It takes me to some other website (keeping my domain in the address bar) with advertisements. Although this may be my DNS provider showing ads since the domain doesn't redirect properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have mod rewrite enabled

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Edit file on *sites-enabled* instead of *sites-available*,

```
cd /etc/apache2
vi sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

For the rewrite rules maybe you need something like this

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,NE,R=301]

# turn on HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,NE,R=301]
```

The ads could be some typo like *www.exmaple.com* or even *www.examlpe.com* instead of *www.example.com* and then your browser ends up on some advertisement domain.

Comment: Ended up being a DNS issue. The www was cached on an old IP I guess. After 2 days it cleared out.